# Stock Android Shortcuts

Tags: stock-android

So I believe the Android keyboard shortcuts vary among version, but what are the stock android shortcuts?

I have not found a complete list anywhere.

I think this should be a community wiki.

Comment: I believe Android Keyboard Shortcuts: Typing may be global haven't tested yet http://www.pcworld.com/article/184656/android_keyboard_shortcuts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completion I am posting the typing shortcuts here.

> • Alt + Spacebar: Insert a special character
>
> • Shift + Del: Delete the character to the right of the cursor
>
> • Alt + Del: Delete an entire line
>
> • Shift + Shift (press it twice): Activate caps-lock; press shift once
>   more to exit
>
> • Alt + Trackball-Left: Move cursor to beginning of line
>
> • Alt + Trackball-Right: Move cursor to end of line
>
> • Alt + Trackball-Up: Move cursor to top of page
>
> • Alt + Trackball-Down: Move cursor to bottom of page
>
> • Shift + Trackball-Left/Right: Highlight text for cutting or copying
>
> • Menu + X: Cut text (will cut all text on-screen unless specific
>   characters are highlighted)
>
> • Menu + C: Copy text to clipboard (will copy all text on-screen
>   unless specific characters are highlighted)
>
> • Menu + V: Paste text from clipboard
>
> • Menu + A: Select all text in the current field